# Youtube Thinks I'm offline [Brave]

Tags: youtube, brave

For a few hours now, Youtube has been behaving strangely for me.
I watch videos on yt in the Brave browser, under Ubuntu 22.04.2, and that has been working fine until about yesterday evening.

Since then, when I go to yt, the home page loads as normal, but when I click on a video or my subscriptions, or try to access my account settings, I get a screen telling me

> Connect to the internet
> You're offline. Check your connection.

My internet connection clearly is okay, as other websites load perfectly fine. Youtube also seems to work fine in the Brave browser on my tablet.

I've tried restarting Brave, turning off all extensions, and restarting the machine, but nothing worked.
I found a suggestion for Windows users to change the preferred DNS server to 8.8.8.8, but that didn't do anything either.

Any ideas?
Thx in advance.

Edit:

1. Firefox can access youtube as normal,
2. Other websites work fine in Brave, including Gmail and Twitch
3. I can access the Youtube Studio for my channel by using the 'my videos' option on the left

Comment: have you tried any other browser?

Comment: Firefox seems to work fine

Comment: Does Brave browser have a "Work Offline" menu option that you accidentally have clicked? Do other **dynamic** web sites (for example GMail.com) work OK?

Comment: Other websites, including Gmail and Twitch.tv still work fine.

Comment: @Zersetzor There seems to be alot threads regarding youtube being blocked on brave browser. Take a look at this: `https://community.brave.com/t/brave-shield-blocking-youtube-videos/308101` Have you blocked elements on any youtube page?

Comment: @Jags  Well, Brave blocks ads all over the place, and I have the SponsorBlock extension installed ( https://sponsor.ajay.app/ ) . But even with all extensions turned off, it doesn't work. And I definitely haven't changed anything for at least a couple of months now. I guess maybe yt changed something that now messes with my set-up? But shouldn't turning off the extensions deal with that?

Comment: @Zersetzor is there anything youtube related in `Custom filters` under `brave://adblock`? If there is... try removing youtube from there and see if it works.

Comment: @Jags Nope, I don't have any custom filters

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem in Brazil now! It was working great yesterday. Chrome works perfect,but Brave is offline for Youtube.

Comment: Same Problem my end, however here is what I have found. **Windows 7** I can not use youtube with brave.
It loads the main search page but as soon as you click a video it says " Connect to the internet. You're offline. Check your connection. **Windows 10** Brave works well with youtube. Brave settings are the same on both machines. Just wondering if this has anything to do with it?
Also this just started happening today.

Comment: @Zersetzor apparently it sounds like youtube have changed things on their end that breaks video-playing on brave browser. I guess brave will fix it soon since quite a few people are affected by this change. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also Brazilian and yesterday it was the same thing as you, but I managed to get back to normal by disabling the tracker and ad blocker